# What's the difference between “que” and “dont”?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, subordonnées, pronoms-relatifs

What's the difference between “que” and “dont”; for example in:

> Je lis le livre que tu m'as donné. (*I'm reading the book you gave me*)
>
> Je lis le livre dont tu m'as parlé. (*I'm reading the book you told me about*)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

*Que* s'utilise avec un verbe *transitif* :

> Tu m'as donné un livre. Je lis le livre que tu m'as donné.

*Dont* s'utilise avec un verbe *intransitif* :

> Tu m'as parlé d'un livre. Je lis le livre dont tu m'as parlé.

Comment: L'emploi d'un verbe intransitif ne suffit pas à déterminer que l'on va utiliser "dont". Voir notamment les constructions *verbe + à + complément*, par exemple *Tu te réfères à un livre. Je lis le livre auquel tu te réfères.*. Dans cet exemple, remplacer *auquel* par *dont* n'est pas possible. *dont* ne remplace que les compléments d'objet introduits par *de*.

Answer (score 15):

As a side note to the answer given by Laurent, even a French native speaker sometimes needs to think about the inverse sentence "Tu m'as donné un livre" to deduce the correct insertion of "que" w.r.t "dont".

In the second sentence "Tu m'as parlé d'un livre", mind the "d'" (or "de" depending on the case), that will lead you to the insertion of "dont".

Not sure it's helpful, though. (That's my first answer here.)

Comment: No, that's exactly the most helpful hint possible. I associate *de* with *dont* as well.

Comment: Agree. Other propositions (à, most notably) command a different way of organizing the relative.

Answer (score 7):

I can't explain the grammatical rules (too much technical terms) but an easy way to remember the difference is that you can translate 'dont' with 'of which'.

(Note that in your two proposed translations, the 'which'/'that' are elided).

Comment: Good point, although I wonder if native english speakers always know when to use "which" and when to use "that".

Comment: And to be honest, I'm not even sure the difference is the same, see for example http://www.betterwritingskills.com/tip-w022.html which seems to imply the words may grammatically be interchangeable. In French, it's not a matter of difference of meaning; one is correct and the other isn't.

Comment: @Joubarc, yes, but 'that' and 'of which' aren't interchangeable (and 'of that' can't be used in the same way). Note also that a more literal translation of your sample phrase would be "I'm reading the book of which you spoke". I'm not suggesting that you should translate like this, just that it's a helpful aide-memoire.

Comment: Ok, my mistake, I hadn't noticed the "of" in "of which".

Answer (score 6):

*Que* replaces a direct object (COD in french *‘Complement d'objet direct‘* ).

*Dont* replaces an object (or person) after ‘de’ like in this example:

> Voici l'enfant. J'ai trouvé le ballon de cet enfant.
>   Voici l'enfant dont j'ai trouvé le ballon.

Answer (score 1):

It can sometimes help to think of *dont* as an invariable synonym for *duquel* (or *de laquelle*, *desquels*, *desquelles*).

Comment: *dont* is not the same as *duquel* (& co.). Example: *Ce livre dont le titre ne me plaisait pas*.

Answer (score 1):

Que = that

Dont = of which, of whom.

"Je lis le livre que tu m'as donné." = I am reading the book that you gave me.

"Je lis le livre dont tu m'as parlé." = I am reading the book of which you spoke.

Comment: *Dont* may also stand for *whose*.

Comment: The problem is in English you can also say "I am reading the book that you spoke to me about." so translating to English doesn't help to know when to use dont or que in French.

Answer (score 1):

Here as in all relative clauses it's a **case problem** (yes there are cases in french). Both dont and que (as duquel, auquel, etc) replace the noun in the relative clause :

- *Dont* is the genitive form and it's used to mark a *complément du nom*
- *Que* is the accusative form and marks a *complément d'objet direct*, a direct objet of the relative clause. "Que" is **also** an ambivalent word equivalent to the English "that" or even "what" as in "je sais que j'ai raison" (i know that i'm right) or in "les mots que j'ai dits" (the words that i said) (and i'm not sure about that s after dits)
- *Auquel* would be the equivalent for an indirect object.