# « Ce dont j'ai envie » ou « ce que j'ai envie » ?

Tags: pronoms-relatifs

Sur Google ngrams, on voit que

> ce dont j'ai envie

est beaucoup plus utilisé que

> ce que j'ai envie

Si on remplace « envie » par « besoin », c'est « dont » qui est le plus commun, mais « ce que j'ai besoin » n'est pas si rare non plus.

Les livres de français insistent que l'on dit « ce dont » dans cet contexte. Est-ce vrai dans la langue courante ? Par exemple, Véronique Sanson a chanté

> Je fais ce que j'ai envie

et même dans les années 1890, Google ngrams pense que « ce que j'ai envie » serait plus commun que « ce dont j'ai envie ».

Comment: est-ce que [ceci](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/112/whats-the-difference-between-que-and-dont?rq=1) pourrais répondre à la question? Dans ce cas, j'irais avec 'J'ai envie de ceci -> ce dont j'ai envie' (associe de avec dont). Ce que j'ai envie sonne faux.

Comment: Attention! En chanson, les paroles peuvent être choisies dans le but de donner du rythme supplémentaire ou du punch, sans forcément être grammaticalement correctes. Prendre des exemples dans des paroles de chanson n'est pas toujours une très bonne idée. (Bon. Ici ça marche bien, mais attention quand même :) )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lorsqu'on fait suivre *envie* par un verbe, par exemple, dans « ce que j'ai envie de dire », le pronom « que » est l'unique possibilité car il est complément d'objet direct de *dire*. Pour désigner directement l'objet d'une envie, *avoir envie* étant suivi de la préposition *de*, on utilise normalement *dont* pour former une relative : « ce dont j'ai envie ».

Cela explique que tu obtiennes les deux possibilités en faisant des recherches sur Google N-gram. Le fait que les proportions ne soient pas tout à fait les mêmes pour « envie » et « besoin » est probablement dû au fait que l'un est plus souvent suivi d'une proposition infinitive que l'autre.

Petite remarque : « Je fais ce que j'ai envie » ne me choque pas car ça se comprend comme une ellipse : « Je fais ce que j'ai envie de faire ». On l'entend parfois en entier, mais c'est aussi courant de ne pas répéter un verbe lorsqu'il est connu. Un exemple similaire serait « Chante ce que tu veux ! » qui sera la plupart du temps compris comme « Chante ce que tu veux chanter ». Seulement dans de très rares cas ce pourrait ne pas être une ellipse et vouloir dire « Fais ta requête en chantant ! ».

Answer (score 3):

Concernant Veronique Sanson, certains articles sur internet indiquent que la chanteuse aurait choisi de chanter "ce que j'ai envie" car « Et je fais ce dont j’ai envie » sonne moins bien à l'oreille, bien que son père n'aimait pas la première tournure.

Answer (score 3):

Si l'on accepte « Chante ce que tu veux [chanter] ! », je ne vois pas pourquoi on condamnerait « Chante ce que tu as envie [de chanter] ! »; dans les deux cas, il y a ellipse du verbe *chanter* dont *que* est le complément d'objet direct.

Au contraire, il serait absurde de dire « Chante ce dont tu as envie ! » sauf si on lui signifiait de chanter son envie.

Ce qui est vrai pour *chanter* l'est tout autant pour *faire* et je maintiens donc que « Fais ce que tu as envie ! » est parfaitement correct.

Answer (score 2):

Je dirais que ça dépend des gens. Certaines personnes prononcent *dont* presque toujours, et à l'opposé il y en a qui n'emploient jamais ce mot. J'essaie de me ranger dans la première catégorie, mais je n'y parviens probablement pas autant que je le voudrais. Dans l'ensemble, je crois que dont est en net recul, et ce d'autant plus qu'on descend dans l'échelle de prestige sociolinguistique.

Answer (score 2):

Les deux expressions ne sont pas interchangeables:

```
Je fais ce que j'ai envie.          Je fais ce dont j'ai envie.
C'est ce dont j'ai envie.           C'est ce que j'ai envie.
C'est ce dont j'ai besoin.          C'est ce que j'ai besoin.
C'est ce que j'ai besoin de faire.  C'est ce dont j'ai besoin de faire.
C'est ce dont j'ai envie de parler. C'est ce que j'ai besoin de parler.
```

« J'ai envie **que** ... » implique « ce **que** j'ai envie ».

« J'ai envie **de** ... » entraîne « ce **dont** j'ai envie ».