# "Celui dont" ou "celui que"

Tags: pronoms-relatifs

Voila je post ici car je n'arrive pas à savoir quand utiliser

- *Tu seras enfin celui que tu as toujours rêvé d'être.*

ou

- *Tu seras enfin celui dont tu as toujours rêvé d'être.*

Pour moi les deux ont le même sens.

Comment: Bienvenue à French Language Stack Exchange. Vous êtes invité à faire le **[tour](https://french.stackexchange.com/tour)** et à visiter le **[Help Center](https://french.stackexchange.com/help)**, et à continuer à poser des questions !

Comment: Marquer cette question comme *duplicate* me semble un peu rapide puisque le verbe *rêver* peut être transitif (direct ou indirect) ou intransitif. J'ai rêvé la mer, j'ai rêvé de la mer, j'ai rêvé que la mer montait etc.

Comment: @Erwan regardez donc toutes les manières d'utiliser le verbe *rêver* là : http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%AAver . Votre 1ère phrase est correcte, la 2ème devrait être "celui dont tu as toujours rêvé" avec une petite nuance : vous avez rêvé de qcq'un qui peut être vous en mieux (comme dans la 1ère phrase) ou une toute autre presonne.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Luke Sawczak: I don't think it is a duplicate. The explanations in the thread you mention don't apply here.

Example of two sentences with the same verb + "de":

- J'ai rêvé d'être cet homme > Cet homme, celui que tu as rêvé d'être
- J'ai rêvé de cet homme > Cet homme, celui dont j'ai rêvé

La différence ici, c'est l'emploi d'un second verbe (être). "Cet homme" est le complément d'objet de "être" dans la première phrase, alors qu'il est le complément de "rêver" dans la seconde. Il nous faut donc une proposition relative.

On ne peut donc pas dire "Tu seras enfin celui dont tu as toujours rêvé d'être", c'est "celui que" qui est bon ici.

Comment: How does [Neikos's answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/117/14023) doesn't apply ?

Comment: I would just say it is not enough in this very specific context. Neiko's example has only one verb and one COD. Erwan's sentence is more complex - you need to add a proposition for the second verb, so use "celui que" instead of "celui dont".

Could anybody improve my answer with a more general rule? Or more examples? Sorry, I am just good to say if a sentence is right or wrong, not why :s

Comment: I feel you're quite repeating what Neiko's answer say, "de qqchose" will become "dont" if the subject is directly introduced by "de". Which is also said under the accepted answer by Romain: "dont ne remplace que les compléments d'objet introduits par de.". No worries, just wording my thoughts :)

Comment: Well, in some cases you can have a "de" that does not result in a "dont", like this :

J'ai rêvé _de_ manger cet homme > _Celui que_ j'ai rêvé de mordre

So I felt this needed a bit more explanations. But maybe I misunderstood the accepted answer, in that case I am sorry!

Comment: Oui, vous avez raison.

Comment: @galenskap in your exemple 'de' is followed by a verb :) No worries :)

Comment: Merci bien, je comprend mieux la nuance maintenant.